# Passar valores de um fragment para uma activity

Tags: java, android

Estou querendo passar o valor de um EditText (que está em um fragment) para um atributo de um objeto de uma activity, porém não estou obtendo sucesso, o Toast da activity retorna null. Segue o código do fragment:

```
public class PerguntaUmFragment extends SlideFragment {
    private PerguntaUmInterface perguntaUmInterface;
    private EditText editMensagem;


    public PerguntaUmFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pergunta_um, container, false);

        editMensagem = view.findViewById(R.id.editMensagem);

        perguntaUmInterface.setMensagem(editMensagem.getText().toString());


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            perguntaUmInterface = (PerguntaUmInterface) context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public interface PerguntaUmInterface {
        void setMensagem(String mensagem);
    }

    public void setPerguntaUmInterface(PerguntaUmInterface perguntaUmInterface) {
        this.perguntaUmInterface = perguntaUmInterface;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class OcorrenciaActivity extends IntroActivity implements PerguntaUmFragment.PerguntaUmInterface {
    private final Ocorrencia ocorrencia = new Ocorrencia();

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(OcorrenciaActivity.this,
                "Mensagem: "+ ocorrencia.getMensagem(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        if (fragment instanceof PerguntaUmFragment) {
            PerguntaUmFragment perguntaUmFragment = (PerguntaUmFragment) fragment;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void setMensagem(String mensagem) {
        ocorrencia.setMensagem(mensagem);

    }
```

Comment: Pq simplesmente vc nao manda um toast direto do Fragment?

Comment: Não, o toast é apenas uma forma de verificar se a mensagem chegou corretamente, o mesmo só imprimi "null" na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe `SharePreference` para compartilhar a informação para essa finalidade ou utilizar outro dois métodos descritos abaixo:

**Criando um SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("EDITEXT1", "string value");  // Salvando dados do seu editext
editor.commit(); // confirmar e salvar seus dados para a SharedPreferences
```

Agora você pode recuperar seus dados como no código abaixo:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String email=pref.getString("EDITEXT1", "");       // Salvando dados de string do seu editext
```

**Pela Instância**

Ou você pode definir um campo de instância em sua Activity e acessá-la subindo a referência `getActivity()` para a `MainActivity` no fragmento:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).filedName.setFragmentOneData(data);
```

**Por Argumentos**

Por ultimo o método utilizando o Bandle para passar informações pelo fragmento:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("someEditTextData",someEditTextData);
SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment ();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

E para recuperar os dados no fragmento (adaptando a sua realidade)

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        showReceivedData.setText(args.getString("someEditTextData"));
    }
```

Comment: Não sei se seria possível, mas poderia se basear e aplicar no meu código?? eu realmente não sei como colocar essa lógica no programa